# How to capture image using two connected devices via Bluetooth/wifi

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-camera, wear-os, android-bluetooth

I'm developing an app for Android Wear in which I want to use the Wear as a remote control. Android Wear will trigger the shutter opened on an Android device(default camera app and without using intent) connected via Bluetooth. I don't know how to go about it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you visited this blogpost about [smartwatch as a camera remote for your phone - android customization](https://www.androidauthority.com/smartwatch-camera-remote-android-customization-684626/)? I think you can get an idea from here.

Comment: @jess Yes, I already have. I'm looking for a technical suggestion.